# 404 error creating container in Azure Storage using CreateIfNotExists method but can with Create method

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

If I try to create a container in my app against the Azure Storage using the CreateIfNotExists method I get a 404 error. But if I change my code to use the Create method everything works fine.

```
public void UploadImageAsync(string containerName, string blobName, byte[] blobData)
{
    CloudBlobContainer container = _client.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
    {
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
    });

    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    blob.UploadFromByteArray(blobData, 0, photo.Data.Length);
}
```

Throws 404 Not found error

```
public void UploadImageAsync(string containerName, string blobName, byte[] blobData)
{
    CloudBlobContainer container = _client.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    try
    {
        container.Create();
        container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        });
    }catch (Exception webException) { }

    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    blob.UploadFromByteArray(blobData, 0, photo.Data.Length);
}
```

Works perfect:

I capture the exception in case I upload two images to the same container. I tried to use
 `if (container.Exists())` 
but it launches the 404 error too.

Any idea what is going on? Why Create works fine but CreateIfNotExists fails?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell us the version of storage client library you're using? Also which operation is failing .... is it CreateIfNotExists() or SetPermissions(). In your 2nd code snippet, you're simply eating the exception. Please try to remove the catch block and see if the code fails there as well. Lastly, it would be helpful if you can trace the request/response through a tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my original code today (using CreateIfNotExists) and everything worked fine again.

I don't know if it was some Azure problem yesterday or what. I'm using the current version (7.2.1.0) and according to Azure no problem was registered yesterday.

My apologies for bothering you with this issue and thanks for the help.